# Retornar valor que não está na outra tabela

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, tabela-banco-de-dados

Eu tenho uma query que retorna solicitações de compras em uma data, as solicitações são três, a 1594, 1595 e 1596.. Essas solitações tem ordem de compras referente a elas que estão em outra tabela e que preciso buscar também. Mas a solicitação 1594 não tem ordem de compra na outra tabela, ou seja, quando no where além da data, coloco que o código da minha solicitação for igual ao código da solicitação da tabela ordem de compra, retorna apenas a 1595 e 1596 porque a 1594 não tem ordem de compra na outra tabela, como fazer para além de buscar as que tem ordem de compras buscar a 1594 que não tem ordem de compra na outra tabela ordem de compra?

```
SELECT 
    oc.cd_ord_com AS COD_ORD_COM,
    oc.dt_ord_com AS DATA_ORD_COM,
    oc.dt_prev_entrega AS DATA_PREV_ENTREGA,
    oc.dt_autorizacao AS DATA_AUTORIZACAO,
    oc.cd_sol_com AS COD_SOLIC_COMPRA

FROM 
 
    sol_com sc, ord_com oc
 
WHERE 

    sc.dt_sol_com BETWEEN TO_date ('07/07/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
    AND TO_DATE ('07/07/2020','dd/mm/yyyy')
    AND sc.cd_sol_com = oc.cd_sol_com
```

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo que realize os cruzamentos de tabelas através do **JOIN**, alem de ser mais fácil de ler o código é mais rápido.

A forma que você está buscando atualmente é essa:

```
FROM sol_com sc

INNER JOIN ord_com oc
  ON sc.cd_sol_com = oc.cd_sol_com
 
WHERE sc.dt_sol_com BETWEEN TO_date ('07/07/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
AND TO_DATE ('07/07/2020','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Para trazer o resultado que deseja utilize o **LEFT JOIN** ou **OUTER JOIN**:

```
FROM sol_com sc

LEFT JOIN ord_com oc
--OUTER JOIN ord_com oc
  ON sc.cd_sol_com = oc.cd_sol_com
 
WHERE sc.dt_sol_com BETWEEN TO_date ('07/07/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
AND TO_DATE ('07/07/2020','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

**INNER JOIN** trás apenas o código que contenha nas duas tabelas, **LEFT JOIN** trás todos os dados da primeira tabela e se houver dados na segunda tabela trás os dados da segunda tabela, já o **OUTER JOIN** trás informações das duas tabelas independente se existe o código relacionado da primeira ou segunda tabela.

Faça o teste e veja qual se encaixa melhor no seu código.

Comment: já consegui resolver isso, porém agora me encontro em algo um pouco mais complicado, eu tenho que buscar data da entrada de nota fiscal apenas das ordens de compra retornada nessa consulta acima.

Comment: Em que tabela está essa tal *data da entrada da nota fiscal*? E como essa tabela se relaciona com a `ord_com`? Tem diagrama entidade-relacionamento?